# python dictionary sorted based on time

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary such as below.

```
d = {
    '0:0:7': '19734',
    '0:0:0': '4278',
    '0:0:21': '19959',
    '0:0:14': '9445',
    '0:0:28': '14205',
    '0:0:35': '3254'
}
```

Now I want to sort it by keys with time priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not sorted, if you want to print it out or iterate through it in sorted order, you should convert it to a list first:

e.g.:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(d.items(), key=parseTime)
#or
for t in sorted(d, key=parseTime):
    pass

def parseTime(s):
    return tuple(int(x) for x in s.split(':'))
```

Note that this will mean you can not use the d['0:0:7'] syntax for sorted_dict though.

Passing a 'key' argument to sorted tells python how to compare the items in your list, standard string comparison will not work to sort by time.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in python have no guarantees on order. There is `collections.OrderedDict`, which retains insertion order, but if you want to work through the keys of a standard dictionary in order you can just do:

```
for k in sorted(d):
```

In your case, the problem is that your time strings won't sort correctly. You need to include the additional zeroes needed to make them do so, e.g. `"00:00:07"`, or interpret them as actual `time` objects, which will sort correctly. This function may be useful:

```
def padded(s, c=":"):
    return c.join("{0:02d}".format(int(i)) for i in s.split(c))
```

You can use this as a `key` for `sorted` if you really want to retain the current format in your output:

```
for k in sorted(d, key=padded):
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) module